# Discord bot active but not responding commands (js)

Tags: javascript, discord, command, bots

I've searched this before but I got nothing, even if there are many questions very similar. I apologize in advance in case I'm posting the same thing.

It is my first time creating a bot. I followed these two videos to reach this point.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_sD9udZnCk&list=RDCMUC08G-UJT58SbkdmcOYyOQVw&start_radio=1&rv=j_sD9udZnCk&

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTGtiCC3iQM&

The problem is that even when the bot is on, it is not catching the ping command. This is the very beginning. I can't continue programming the bot while he can't catch any command.

Here's my code of main.js. The only thing I changed is `new Discord.client();` to `new Discord.Client({ intents: 100 });` because it seems that changed recently.

I still don't know what is an intent and what number should I put there, but it seems that the bot turns on when I write down `node .`.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 100 });
// idk which number of intents should I put here

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ivancódigo funcionando!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{

    /*if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ping`)){
            message.channel.send('pong!');*/

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
})

client.login('TOKEN');
```

When I write -ping in the text box of discord I still got no response. I've tried many codes and still the same, but I cleaned most of the code to keep it comfortable for you to read, just keeping the important thing. The mistake must be anywhere in the part of Discord receiving this code instructions but I don't know how to solve it.

Where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because wrong intetnts, this work if you have discord.js v13.
Try something like this and delete intents that you don't need:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [
  "GUILDS",
  "GUILD_MEMBERS",
  "GUILD_BANS",
  "GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS",
  "GUILD_INTEGRATIONS",
  "GUILD_WEBHOOKS",
  "GUILD_INVITES",
  "GUILD_VOICE_STATES",
  "GUILD_PRESENCES",
  "GUILD_MESSAGES",
  "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS",
  "GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING",
  "DIRECT_MESSAGES",
  "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS",
  "DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING"
  ]
});
```

Comment: It threw me a new error.

const client = new Client({ intents: [     
               ^

ReferenceError: Client is not defined

Then I changed to new Discord.Client...

and threw me this:

throw new Error(WSCodes[error.code]);
              ^

Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.

Comment: ok, I searched about that, I may be getting closer. Thanks. I will comment if I solve my issues or in any other case.

Comment: Very much thanks mate, i just deleted GUILD_PRESENCES (for some reason doesnt work) and put new Discord.Client(...
Now it works. Now I understand what is an intent. Now I can continue ^^